# Smarty variable in array index

Tags: smarty

Have months array `$months('January', 'February', 'May')`

and want show this month in loop

```
{for $foo=1 to 3}
    {$months[$foo]}
{/for}
```

I get white page, what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you're defining the array properly:

```
$months = array('January', 'February', 'May');
```

Then, make sure the indices are correct (in PHP array indices start from 0):

```
{for $foo=0 to 2}
    {$months[$foo]}
{/for}
```